# How does ENS prevent frontrunning attacks?

Tags: namecoin, ethereum

Namecoin uses commitments to hide the domain. ENS uses simple hash, which is not hiding.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get the domain name on the ENS is to win at the target name auction. 
So there is no need to hide the name. 
ENS uses the name hash for converting arbitrary length string into bytes32.